# Can I add a resize function to this script?

Tags: php

I am not really good in PHP but the images that will show on the webpage of mine will be the main resolution. I would like to downscale it but I have no clue how.

```
<?php
$images = glob('*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE); // Formats to look for

$num_of_files = 2; // Number of images to display

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $num_of_files--;

    if ($num_of_files > -1) // This made me laugh when I wrote it
    {
        echo "<b>" . $image . "</b><br>"
            . "Created on " . date('D, d M y H:i:s', filemtime($image)) . "<br>"
            . "<img src='" . $image . "'><br><br>";
    } // Display images
    else {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking about. Do you want to resize file on the server or to make it smaller in the user browser?

Comment: If you wish to decrease file size but keep image quality: http://compressor.io (Unknown if they have an API for this) Otherwise: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to resize the image shown in the browser, right? In that case some simple styling would do the trick:

```
. "<img src='" . $image . "' style='width: 200px'><br><br>";
```

Change the 200px to whatever width you want, the height will scale proportionally.

You should also have a look on how to use [CSS classes](http://www.w3ctutorial.com/css-basic/css-id-class).

If you rather want to scale the actual image file (i.e. if it resides on your server), check out [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).